# Update a Word file that has been created in ACC

Tags: file-upload, autodesk-forge

I need to update a Word file that has been created in ACC. I can download the file, but when I try to upload it again, I get the error: 'Only the bucket creator is allowed to access this api.'
It seems you can only upload files to buckets the application has created. Is this correct ?

Note that I don't want to create a new version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were uploading the new file via the bucket `wip.dm.prod` directly, which is owned by Autodesk Cloud products, e.g. BIM360 Docs/ Autodesk Docs(ACC Docs). It's expected that you cannot do that directly, since you're not the bucket owner.

To upload a new file version to Autodesk Cloud products, you will need to do the following.

1. Request a storage location: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document/#step-5-create-a-storage-object
2. Create Additional Versions of the File for the updated file: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document/#step-5-create-a-storage-object

**Note.** Forge Data Management API is forward compatible with ACC.